# Problems compiling Wireshark from Source (SVN) during .calling /configure

Tags: networking, interface, source-code

Today I've tried to compile Wireshark locally (no make install) from SVN as I've done before.
When I call .configure I receive an error, that the file gtk/doxygen.cfg.in was not available:

```
 config.status: error: cannot find input file: `gtk/doxygen.cfg.in'
```

I have no clue what to do to avoid this problem. Has anyone else encountered tthis problem or is somehow able to give me some tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. The solution is (of course :-/ ) quite easy:

make distclean
./configure
make

... ready (or using cmake, what I didn't recognized)